# using dataframe names in a loop in R

Tags: r

I am using the following code to access data frames df1,df2 and df3 in a loop and rename them. This gives me an error. How do I tell R that its a data frame not a

```
for(i in c(df1,df2,df3)) {
  colnames(data.frame(i))=c("var1","var2","var3")
}
```

Comment: Create a list and use `lapply` to chnage names: `lapply(list(df1, df2, df3), function(x) { names(x) <- paste0("var", 1:3); x })`

Comment: @markus or use `setNames(x, paste0("var", 1:3))` and avoid returning object at end.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also, when my function is passing a string let's say "count" and I want to create multiple variables using it in the function, like a_count b_count c_count how do I proceed?

Comment: @abhi post another question whit an short example showing the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a list instead

```
dfl=list(df1,df2,df3)
  for(i in 1:length(dfl)) {
    colnames(dfl[[i]])<-c("var1","var2","var3")
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also, when my function is passing a string let's say "count" and I want to create multiple variables using it in the function,  like  a_count b_count c_count how do I proceed?

Comment: Same answer: use a list instead. [Reading this would probably be good for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061).